# javascript into HTML file and test coverage

Tags: javascript, jestjs, code-coverage

I'm working with a lot of js into HTML files. Is there a possibility to include those javascript into the final coverage report using jest?

Example:

```js
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script>

      // Is there any way to include the coverage of this function to the coverage report?
      function doSomething(a, b){
        return a*b
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```